# Showing Numbers inbetween two numbers on the same row

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to achieve is there are 2 whole numbers in column A & B on the same row. I want to fill the row from Column C to show the whole numbers increments of one between the two numbers.

i.e.

```
   A  B  C  D E F G H I J K L
   1 10  1  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In Excel? Please update your question and tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is Excel and you can open the VBE Editor to use VBA

Here's a macro you can run or call via a button

See the comments in the code to understand what it's doing with the Dataseries fill function

```
Sub FillData()
    Dim intStopAt   As Integer

    ' Set to cell indicated low end of range
    Cells(1, 1).Select

    ' Fill in "Start At" Number
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = ActiveCell.Value

    ' Retrieve and use stop number to fill in series
    intStopAt = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, Step:=1, Stop:=intStopAt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys huge help. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below code assumes you have no header and that your value in `A1` is always `1`, and your value in `B1` is the number you want to count to.

This can be modified to be more dynamic, but taking your question as is, this should work for you.

1) Check number to count to (`CountTo`)
2) Run loop for `1 to CountTo` and auto-populate your column headers

To run: Open VBE and paste this code on the sheet where you wish to run it.

```
Sub Counter()

Dim CountTo As Integer
CountTo = Range("B1").Value

For i = 1 To CountTo
    Cells(1, i + 2) = i
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without VBA, perhaps not as neat initially as @dbmitch's answer because the formula has to go across to the maximum possible number.

- A1 is start number, > 0
- B1 is end number (> A1)
- In Cell C1 enter `=A1`
- In Cell D1 enter `=IF(AND(C1<$B1,C1>=$A1),C1+1,"")` and then
  drag/fill right as far as you need to.

I have formulated the code so that you can now select the filled rows (A through to wherever) and fill down.

A simple explanation:

- C1 sets the start of the list
- The `AND` formula in D1 onwards checks that the immediate left cell (for D1 this is C1, for E1 this is D1 etc.) is less than the end number and greater than the start number.
- If the conditions are true, use the immediate left cell value + 1 as the result.
- If the conditions are false, insert a blank.

Further checking can be done, I have assumed in the above solution that the numbers are positive and increasing.

- You can use helper columns to indicate if you should increase or decrease (i.e. `+1` or `-1` as required.
- Using a `blank` as the other answer falls down if the numbers go from -ve to +ve. In this case, you could use another symbol (e.g. `x`) and check for that in the `AND` function as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers) ' reference column A cells from row 1 down to last not empty one with a "constant" (i.e. not a formula result) numeric content
        For Each cell In .Cells 'loop through referenced range
            cell.Offset(, 2).Resize(, cell.Offset(, 1).Value - cell.Value + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=COLUMN()-COLUMN(C3)+RC1" 'write proper formula in current cell adjacent cells
        Next
        .CurrentRegion.Value = .CurrentRegion.Value ' get rid of formulas and leave values only
    End With
End Sub
```